# Google Cache: Blank Page (Responsive Design)

Tags: google, google-index, cache, responsive-webdesign, google-cache

I've been aware of this issue for sometime but sadly not had the downtime to address, but I want to ensure that its actually a problem before wasting my time. The problem that I have is that ***[Google's cache displays a blank page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1LOmiH9nowMJ:https://www.bybe.net/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)***, but heres the thing, if you reduce the `VIEWPOINT` the page displays fine.

Basiclly [my website](https://www.bybe.net/) uses 3 media queries that define the navigation of the site, like so:

- Small Screens (`max-width: 40em`) uses a Hamburger Menu
- Medium Screens (`max-width: 64em`) uses a standard top bar menu
- Large Screens (`min-width: 64.063em`) uses a custom slide menu

Both the Small and Medium viewpoints work using the cached version but sadly the Large does not, Bing works absolutely fine! so this brings me to the question(s):

- Should I be concerned by this?
- What's causing this to happen?

Comment: This is odd... I was checking out your site. I go to the portfolio section then when I hovered over portfolio, I saw the word portfolio in huge letters half off the screen. I'm using Opera 11.60 for linux. All I could say is the more compatible your website is to all browsers in the world, the more correct it will be displayed by other rendering engines because some engines are old and cannot understand new syntax (like the CSS vw or wv measurement unit)

Comment: Hey Mike, Opera 11.60 is more than 5 years old and the HTML5/CSS3 spec has new standards, new code & so forth. I believe the menu issue is caused by `width: calc(75% - 100px) `, I suppose I could add `width: -o-calc(75% - 100px);` then again considering I've had 1 person (you) in the past 12 months using this version it would be a complete waste of time tweaking the experience for a target audience I don't need. 99.999% of my customers do not have a issue using the site, in fact I don't want the type of customers who use old browsers because those type of sites will suck in my portfolio :)

Comment: @SimonHayter i think it could be at least partly a browser issue. See it in Win7 at latest Chrome, but not in latest FF (here is the cache page blank with and without resize). Another thought: G crawls with different settings. After it realized, the site has media queries, it crawled as user with low display size.

Comment: Hi Evgeniy, for me Chrome, FireFox and MS Edge are the same. When I do a Google Fetch in Webmaster tools its fine, its pretty odd.

Comment: I'd like to support every browser because there are some people who couldn't afford to upgrade. Heck, if Africans begin browsing my site, I might be rich and famous. why? because Africa is far away (which means higher time to first byte) and because they probably can't afford to upgrade.

Comment: @Mike not sure where your getting your research from because your so far from the Truth. Africa for example has more users browsing the net using Android devices than desktop computers, the majority of those users use Jellybean upwards, which means the latest Chrome, Firefox and so forth...  Also, if Africa is a target region of yours (which I doubt) then you should be using a CDN proxy to reduce your first byte. Cloudflare operates in several data centres in both south and north Africa.

Comment: Should also note that a lot of so called visitors from the Middle East, Asia and Africa will not be real people as these are often hacked botnets running on home broadband which scan websites for emails, data and vulnerabilities, they will appear as normal users with valid browser user agents, its impossible to tell other than watching their behaviour. Africa is home for some of the biggest botnets around because the continent is home to the world’s most vulnerable computers. About 80 percent of the African population lacks even rudimentary knowledge of information technologies.

Comment: Hey mate did you fixed it because I see for me it is okay I tried from 320x480 up to 1920x900 and it was just fine.
Win 10, Latest Firefox I also tried Chrome, Edge and Opera it is still fine. Maybe your cache has expired and has been reloaded?
http://prntscr.com/a6x4cl

Comment: I didn't touch it... seems it must of been a fault at Google.

Comment: It would seem this was a temporary issue by Google and has resolved itself.

Comment: "I've been aware of this issue for sometime" - and suddenly within a few days of posting a question about it here it "fixes itself"! Big brother is watching! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause are your media queries. Google crawls with different settings and after it realizes, there are media queries, it crawls with user agent, which display size is lower as full screen.

I tested this issue at Chrome and FF: the page begins to be displayed after the window is resized to 1026px width: it seems like would your media queries hide the content after 1026px:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The media queries does not hide the content on the live site through, the resizing of the viewpoint works fine.

Comment: do you realized, that your site version, which loads for displays bigger then 1026 width, is completely not cached? the cache site is empty, till the display get 1026px, the the cache shows the site version for displays lower as 1026px.

Comment: Yes, lol... your telling me all things I know... question is why, and should I be concerned :)

Comment: You have btw. in both css files12 different min and max width settings, and more then 3 media queries, based on them: 4 different min-width: 40.063em, 64.063em, 90.063em, 120.063em, and 8 different max-width: 31.5em, 40em, 64 em, 71.25rem, 1150px, 90 em, 120 em, 99999999em. I'm pretty sure, that they do the mess:) Unbundle this knot!

Comment: There is no limit how many media queries you can have as long as they exercute in order which they all do. The issue seems to be related to `.js .sbMainContent { position: absolute; }`, using FireBug if you add `position: relative;` it kinda displays some of it, but this doesn't explain why... :)